# Custom django field in admin-form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget, django-models

I`m trying to create form field for Django admin backend
In database it should be CharField field, contains "0" and "1" values with 24*7 length.
In admin panels I want to see them as 7 fields with 24 checkboxes each.
The code:

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from places.widgets import *
from places.fields import *

class Place(models.Model):
    …
    time =          HoursWorkByWeekField()
    …
```

fields.py

```
from django.forms import fields
from django.db import models

from places.widgets import HoursWorkByWeekWidget

class HoursWorkByWeekField(models.CharField):
    widget = HoursWorkByWeekWidget

    def __init__(self):
        super(HoursWorkByWeekField, self).__init__(max_length=24*7, min_length=24*7)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return list(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        result = []
        for i in range(24*7):
            if value[i] :
                result += ['1']
            else :
                result += ['0']
        return ''.join(result)
```

widgets.py

```
from django.forms import widgets

class HoursWorkByDayWidget(widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, attrs=None):
        choices = range(0,24,1)
        return widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple.render(self, name, attrs, choices)

class HoursWorkByWeekWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
        )
        super(HoursWorkByWeekWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)
```

When I try to syncdb i have error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases unhashable type: 'dict'
```